# Sort Numbers/Text in one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote the following code to sort data on my workbook

```
With gwksSheet
    With .Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Columns(glAssetTypeCol), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Columns(glFundCodeCol), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Columns(glOberonCol), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(glLastRow, glLastCol))
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

In the column "glOberonCol" I have numbers (e.g. 2561236) & Text (e.g. 2561236R).  When it sorts it sorts the numbers and then the text.  I want to sort it so I get 2561236 & 2561236R beside each other.  What do I need to do.  Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Ciaran.

Comment: Will there be cases like `2561236RR` or `R2561236R` or `R2561R236R` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps bellow:

- Create another column
- Add formula "=TEXT(RC[-1],"###")"
- Copy this value and override the old values forcing Excel to see numbers as strings.
- Now you can use your macro or just use Filter button.